# passing arguments in tkinter's protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW") function on python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a simple python program with one thread handling UI and another “Background stuff”.  I'd like to run a function when the user tries to exit my application a dialogue choice appears.

When I run the following code the function “on_closing()” runs automatically. As I understand I have to pass the function name only in the protocol function but I need a couple of arguments.

```
class MainWindow:

    def __init__(self, master):

        master.resizable(0, 0)
        master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing(master))
        do_stuff('...')

    def on_closing(self, master):
        do_stuff('...')
        self.Destroy(master)

def call_window_manager(title):
    do_stuff(title)
    root = Tk()
    mw = MainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()


def call_tools(title, mainwindow, master):
    do_stuff(title)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    do_stuff('main line')

    p1 = mp.Process(target=call_window_manager, args=('Window Manager Thread',))
    p2 = mp.Process(target=call_tools, args=('Tools Thread',))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

How do I pass arguments then? Am I approaching this with the wrong way?

Ps: what’s the best way to terminate the other thread at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass arguments to `protocol`'s callback function using `lambda`. As in replace:

```
master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing(master))
```

with:

```
master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda arg=master: self.onclosing(arg))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: `master` iteself is not some variable that will change over time so there is no reason to do `arg=master`. Simply `master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: self.on_closing(master))` will work fine here. On that note it is likely to be better to just do `master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)` and have the `on_closing` method do `self.master.destroy()`.